# I just started working on vb.net and came across this I want to know what g.mods.count-1 to 0 step-1 mean in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I just started working on vb.net and came across this I want to know what  g.mods.count-1 to 0 step-1 mean in vb.net

```
If rsp.ModCnt > 0 AndAlso g.ModsSpecified Then
    For i As Integer = g.Mods.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Dim itemKey As String = String.Format("1__{0}", g.Mods(i).Name)
        g.Mods.RemoveAt(i)
    Next
End If
```

Comment: The For loop's control variable, i, is being run from a starting value of g.Mods.Count -1 to an ending value of 0 in steps of -1.

Answer (score 2):

This bit of code has a few interesting things in it.

The `AndAlso` is a short-circuit. If `rsp.ModCnt > 0` evaluates to `False`, the second condition will never be evaluated.

The start value of `i` is `g.Mods.Count - 1` and the end value is `0`. On each iteration the value of `i` will decrease by 1.

A simpler version might look like...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lst As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4}
    For i = lst.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        lst.RemoveAt(i)
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(lst.Count.ToString)
End Sub
```

On the first iteration, `i` will be 3, lst.Count -1.

On the next iteration `i` will be 2 and so on until the last iteration where `i` will be 0.

If the coder tried to start the loop with zero and go up to the highest index, `lst.Count -1` then we would get an Index Out of Range error.

```
For i = 0 To lst.Count - 1 'The default is Step 1
```

Try it and see. When we remove the first item from the list at index 0 the next item becomes index 0. Second iteration remove index 1. The length (.Count) of the list is now 2 (two items have been removed), the highest index is 1 but on the next iteration we try to remove index 2 which doesn't exist. This is why we use highest index to lowest index and `Step -1`.

As a side note the line

```
Dim itemKey As String = String.Format("1__{0}", g.Mods(i).Name)
```

is really useless because it is just overwriting the value on each iteration and falls out of scope at the end of the For block.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an error in this code unrelated to the question. Because `ItemKey` is defined locally within the scope of the loop, we can reduce everything down to this single line:

```
If rsp.ModCnt > 0 AndAlso g.ModsSpecified Then g.Mods.Clear()
```

As for the question, the code loops over the `g.Mods` collection **backwards**. That's what `Step -1` means.

The reason to loop backwards, rather than from front to back, is because it removes items as it goes. If it went from front to back, as items were removed the index of all the items following would change, causing you to skip items when `i` is incremented. Additionally, that could mean trying to read past the end of the collection, if `g.Mods.Count` is not rechecked.

But, again, from the code we can see, the whole thing could be replaced with simple `.Clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple for-loop ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement)).

A for loop runs a set number of times (or should be run as such).
`For i As Integer` declares an integer variable with name `i` for the scope of the loop body.
`= g.Mods.Count - 1` assigns the value of `g.Mods.Count - 1` to the variable `i`.
`g` is likely some class object with `Mods` as a public property. `Count` is a Property of `Mods`. `Mods` is likely an object of a collection class such as `List` ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8)) or another class that implements the `Enumerable` interface ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8)).
As per the For-Loop syntax, Step is indicating how the counter variable (that's `i`) is changed after each iteration. In this case it's decreased by 1 every time. Step can be omited, then `Step 1` is implied.

In short this loop goes over the indexes of some Enumerable called `Mods` backwards.

Some other things not directly concerning the question:

- A local variable itemKey is created inside the loop but never used. Unless the call of the Property `Name` does something (it shouldn't, that'd be bad style), this line can be removed.
- The index of enumerables starts at 0, thus the last index is `Count - 1`
- The loop goes backwards because it removes the elements of Mods. But this is slow. You can simply use `Clear()` on objects whose class implements IEnumerable to delete all elements of the collection.
- The entire loop can be removed and replaced with `g.Mods.Clear()`